# In bash tee is making function variables local, how do I escape this?

Tags: linux, bash, tee, bash-function

I have stucked with a bash scipt which should write both to stdout and into file. I'm using functions and some variables inside them. Whenever I try to redirect the function to a file and print on the screen with tee I can't use the variables that I used in function, so they become local somehow.
Here is simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGV=/root/log

function var()
{
echo -e "Please, insert VAR value:\n"
read -re VAR
}
var 2>&1 | tee $LOGV
echo "This is VAR:$VAR"
```

Output:

```
[root@testbox ~]# ./var.sh   
Please, insert VAR value:

foo
This is VAR:
[root@testbox ~]#
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Responding on @Etan Reisner suggestion to use
`var 2>&1 > >(tee $LOGV)`

The only problem of this construction is that log file dosn't receive everything...

```
[root@testbox~]# ./var.sh
Please, insert VAR value: 

foo 
This is VAR:foo
[root@testbox ~]# cat log 
Please, insert VAR value:
```

Comment: I think your problem is that since you're using a pipe (into `tee`), the initial invocation of `var` is happening in a subshell.  So you set an environment variable in that subprocess, but doesn't affect the environment of the main (parent) process.

Comment: Do you want the prompt "Please, insert..." to to to the output file?

Comment: Thanks, yes I guess this is the subshell issue, but can't fix it yet.
William Pursell, yes, I do!

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? You need to avoid variable assignment in sub-shells if you want them to affect the main shell. If the post snippet is your ultimate goal then your only solution (as far as I know) is to replace the pipe with something like `> >(tee $LOGV)` to use process substitution and output redirection instead of the pipe.

Comment: Amazing, Etan! That's what I need, yes post snippet. It works like a charm. Please, post full answer in order I could accept it! Thanks a lot, have spent few hours on this ...

Comment: As an aside -- `tee $LOGV` is not safe: If `LOGV` was a filename with spaces, `tee` would then write to more than one file. Always quote your expansions: `tee "$LOGV"`. Also, all-caps variable names are reserved by convention for system use; try to be in the habit of using at least one lower-case letter in your own variables' names, to prevent overriding a system variable by mistake. (See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace).

Comment: @Charles Duffy, thank you for recommendations, will keep in mind!

Comment: Re: "log doesn't receive everything" -- it doesn't receive local echo of what the user typed, because that's *local echo* -- it's not on stdout or stderr, but purely a terminal construct.

Comment: As a terminology note -- they're not "local" as such; the variables in question are global to the shell they're running in; the problem is that the shell they're running in is a subshell that exits when the pipeline is finished. For this reason, you couldn't just use, say, `declare -g` to force them to be global and have that provide any useful effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a variant of [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

```
var 2>&1 | tee $LOGV
```

...like any shell pipeline, has the option to run the function `var` inside a subprocess -- and, in practice, behaves this way in bash. (The POSIX sh specification leaves the details of which pipeline components, if any, run inside the parent shell undefined).

---

Avoiding this is as simple as not using a pipeline.

```
var > >(tee "$LOGV") 2>&1
```

...uses process substitution (a ksh extension adopted by bash, not present in POSIX sh) to represent the `tee` subprocess through a filename (in the form `/dev/fd/##` on modern Linux) which output can be redirected to without moving the function into a pipeline.

---

If you want to ensure that `tee` exits before other commands run, use a lock:

```
#!/bin/bash
logv=/tmp/log

collect_var() {
        echo "value for var:"
        read -re var
}
collect_var > >(logv="$logv" flock "$logv" -c 'exec tee "$logv"') 2>&1
flock "$logv" -c true # wait for tee to exit

echo "This is var: $var"
```

---

Incidentally, if you want to run multiple commands with their output being piped in this way, you should invoke the `tee` only once, and feed into it as appropriate:

```
#!/bin/bash
logv=/tmp/log
collect_var() { echo "value for var:"; read -re var; }

exec 3> >(logv="$logv" flock "$logv" -c 'exec tee "$logv"') # open output to log
collect_var >&3 2>&3         # run function, sending stdout/stderr to log
echo "This is var: $var" >&3 # ...and optionally run other commands the same way
exec 3>&-                    # close output
flock "$logv" -c true        # ...and wait for tee to finish flushing and exit.
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but there are some obstacles while using the methods you've recommended:
1) During first variant the log file doesn't receive a final echo part + it is not appending (easy manageable by `tee -a`, though);
2) Here the some unexpected behavior happens: 1) inserted value foo is printed with echo line, like this: `fooThis is VAR:foo`; 2)  Echo is not redirected to file; 3) The script doesn't exit after echoing `fooThis is VAR:foo`, though, it prompts for input: 
`[root@testbox ~]# 

`

Comment: I don't think I follow what you're trying to accomplish well enough for the objections above to make sense. Could you extend your question to describe *exactly* what contents you expect in the log file after the command is run, and *exactly* what behavior or output leads you to believe that the script isn't exiting when it should? (As for (1), your original pipe-based code didn't append to logv either, so I don't follow why it's a problem that this doesn't).

Comment: Charles Duffy, the final goal is to have function with defined global variables inside that may be used outside of the function while redirecting stdout/stderr of script execution to file and screen.
P.S. You're right, my bad, I didn't mention about appending, sorry.

Comment: I've added a full end-to-end example that demonstrates using locking to ensure that `tee` exits before other parts of the command are run.

Comment: Charles Duffy, thanks for full example it is much more understandable now. But, I still have one question to ask... What if I'd like to ensure `tee` exits **after** the execution of commands, how should I use this construct (have tried back and forth, can't figure out). Thanks!

Comment: "the execution of commands", meaning the execution of those commands that feed into the `tee`? Because that's already guaranteed -- you can't put the `flock` until after the commands that feed into the tee as a matter of course. `tee` won't ever exit until after its stdin feed has been closed; you don't need to worry about it exiting early -- the only case you need to worry about is it exiting *late*.

Comment: ...now, if you want "commands", plural, to feed into the `tee`, then you want to use the former exec form. I'll update to show that combined with the locking.

Comment: By the way, if your `echo "This is var: $var"` *also* fed into the tee, ie. was in the `>&3` section before the FD was closed with the multi-line form, then you wouldn't have the trouble with it being out-of-sync.

Comment: Charles, that was exactly what I was trying to accomplish! Thank you for all your answers and extended examples!